# SQL Server BULK INSERT - Linux/RHEL error

Tags: sql-server, linux, bulkinsert

I'm running below bulk insert query (via a stored procedure) against SQL Server 2019 which resides in a Linux / RHEL VM.  Upon execution, I get this error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.Import_Store, Line 25
> [Batch Start Line 14]
>
> Cannot bulk load. The file "/home/user1/FileStorage/Store1.csv" does
> not exist or you don't have file access rights.

This error message is not correct - i.e. the file exists physically on the VM at the specified path and with correct permissions (everybody got full permission!).

Any insight is highly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Store
    FROM '/home/user1/FileStorage/Store1.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

FYI - I tried many options like use C:\ or C:/ instead of /home, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: The account where your `sql server` is running for, does this also has full permission?

Comment: Yes, it's sa (admin) account.

Comment: I very much doubt that the `mssql` user/group has access to `user1`'s home directory (and more importantly it shouldn't). Put the file somewhere else, where the `mssql` group has access to read (and write) to.

Comment: @Larnu shouldn't need write surely?

Comment: I can't recall if SQL Server tries to lock the file or not on Linux, @Charlieface . I would suggest it likely would though, so that the file can't be altered while it's loading, which would require write access.

Comment: @Larnu Normally a read lock will prevent writers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Larnu for your comment above.  That made me do something that resolved my problem.  Here is how I solved it for anybody who is in the same boat.

I basically created a brand new shared folder at root on Linux VM.  Then created a new user group and gave it full access to the shared folder.  Then I added the user "mssql" to the group.  Now my SQL Server can access the location without any errors!

```
sudo mkdir -p /SharedFolder

sudo groupadd SharedUsers

sudo chgrp -R SharedUsers /SharedFolder
sudo chmod -R 2775 /SharedFolder

sudo usermod -a -G SharedUsers mssql
```